# How do I generate a positive long integer in C#?

Tags: c#, random

How do I generate a positive long integer in C#?

Background information: I have no shared state, and am inserting entries into dynamodb, which has no auto-incrementing primary keys.  A typical pattern is to insert a guid, check for collisions; depending on how occupied the table is, this is a working solution.  I would like to use a modified strategy, where instead of using guids (16 bytes) I will use positive longs (63 bits).

Justification that this is a safe plan:

I expect to eventually use at most a hundred billionth (1/10**8) of the total available space.

```
2**63 == 9223372036854775808
```

if I store 100b records, occupancy is:

```
2**63/10**11 == 92233720 ~= 10**8
```

Which means the chance of collision is about one every hundred million tries.  Since I detect collisions upon insert, that it is acceptable to have to retry the generation at that frequency.

So the question is:

How can I generate random positive longs in C#?

Comment: Standard id conventions mean you should let it generate by your db... Just randomly generating one would result in failed insert queries that can lead to many problems if you don't account for that.. that's the whole reasoned all DBs have auto incrementing IDs..

Comment: DynamoDB Does not support random autogenerated ID.  I will be checking for duplicates on insert.  Also, long space is enough for this domain.

Comment: The question is how to generate such a number, which is not built-in to C# standard libraries, and which has a reasonable business use.  Comments such as "well, you shouldn't do that" are not relevant.

Comment: Get the id field, initialize to 0, increment by 1 `id++`

Comment: @crunchy I do not have a shared state among all clients beyond the db itself, so there is no way to coordinate that.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(id) from table;` new id = max(id) + 1;

Comment: @crunchy two points.  Dynamo doesn't operate on SQL syntax which you provided.  Also, the table does not store the store the max value.  I expect to insert 100b rows eventually.  I also don't have a guaranteed shared client state.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks for how to generate positive longs in C#.  This code does that. 
 The question outlines a plan to handle duplicates.  Therefore the following code does not generate PKs, or claim uniqueness - it claims well-distribution and is relying on the outlined framework for handling longs.

So, here is how to generate positive longs in C#, which is what the question asked for:

```
public static long GeneratePositiveLong(Random random)
{
    byte[] buf = new byte[8];
    random.NextBytes(buf);

    //the last byte must be from 0-127
    buf[7] = buf[7] &= 0x7f;
    long res = BitConverter.ToInt64(buf, 0);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Random does not mean unique which would be required of any PK

Comment: To ensure a positive/unsigned byte you could just mask out the potential sign bit, i.e. `buf[7] &= 0x7f;`

Comment: @Plutonix It depends on the domain size how likely collisions are and thus how feasible their use is. It is somewhat common to use GUIDs as primary keys, which are also mostly random, although 128bit instead of 64bit like long.

Comment: A Unique Id is unique no matter the domain size.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use a table to keep track of the next PK to use for your other table(s). Lock this table when you need a new primary key, read the current value, increment it, then unlock. This way multiple clients will not overlap keys.

Comment: Yeah, I could use the dynamoDb as the store for the primary key, but there would be problems - too many requests to one key, and there might be locking issues.  There are distributed keyallocation services, but I'm hoping that since my occupancy is so low, I can get by without having to create one.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is you could use currenttimestamp in nanoseconds which would be unique so that you can use it as a unique primary key as well

Comment: This is roughly equivalent to using long - the question specified long for other reasons (mainly so that we use the entire id space).  Limiting it to currentTimestamp would work if we had nanosecond resolution on time - but that resolution may not be available.  Also there is fun stuff like daylight savings.

Comment: well still your timestamp in nano seconds at any point of time will still be unique and in order for the records to be repeated you should have very huge set of data entries with unsigned long you will a very large range again as i said this is one possible option